# Add landing page before homepage - Magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a landing page before the homepage in Magento, but it seems everywhere I look the documentation is very vague or the forums are hard to understand. I am fairly new to Magento but am very savvy with coding. Can anyone give me some instructions? or guide me in the right direction...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I did it one time. I needed to verify a cookie before showing a pre-home.phtml template file.

I created a new module called "Pagina", and set on it's etc/config.xml:

```
<page>

            <layouts>

                <pre_home module="pagina" translate="label">

                        <label>Pre-home</label>

                        <template>page/pre-home.phtml</template>

                        <layout_handle>pre_home</layout_handle>

                </pre_home>

            </layouts>

        </page>
```

The cookie validation was made via JavaScript, so if a crawler robots visits the site, we redirect to the correct page. In the layout/page.xml in the **cms_index_index** node, we putted:

```
<cms_index_index>
...
        <reference name="after_body_start">

            <block type="page/html_head" after="-" name="index.js.beginning">

                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/prehome.js</name></action>

            </block>

        </reference>
...
</cms_index_index>
```

In the JS file on /js/prehome.js:

```
var c_name = 'city';

if(window.location.toString().indexOf('pre-home') == -1){

    var first_visit = true;

    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)

    {

      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));

      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);

      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

      if (x==c_name)

        {

         first_visit=false;

        }

    }   

    if(first_visit){
//you must define URL_SITE with site base url
        location.href = URL_SITE + 'pre-home';

    }

    

}else{

    document.getElementById("sp").onclick = function(){

        var exdate=new Date();

        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 365);

        var c_value=escape('SP') + "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString();

        document.cookie= c_name + "=" + c_value;

    }

}
```

Note that I created another escope in the same dir as /default, named /pre-home. So we need to have another handle, the **pre_home** layout handler , and some JS is inside template/[yourscope]/pre-home instead /default. But the pre-home.phtml must be at /default/template/page/pre-home.phtml as mentioned in config.xml.

Basically I have:

> app/code/local/Namespace/Pagina/etc/config.xml
>
> app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/page.xml
>
> app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/page/pre-home.phtml
>
> skin/frontend/mytheme/default/js/prehome.js

I hope this can help you.